# Formal definition of a wave

Tags: definition

I have never seen a formal definition of a wave-like function. By wave-like function, I mean, intuitively, something similar to the sine function. The closest definition I have gotten is "finite linear combination of sine functions". But this still leaves a lot of stuff out. Is there a text where there is a good definition of wave-like functions?

Comment: What a good question! Unfortunately I think there is no answer. Somebody said “physics is full of good theorems. Unfortunately, there are no definitions”. This is one of those missing definitions.

Comment: I would generally consider a "wave" to be a solution to the wave-equation, $(\partial_t  - c^2\Delta)u= 0$. The general solution to this equation is $u(x,t) = F(x-ct)+G(x+ct)$ which is the sum of two "travelling waves" with $F(x-ct)$ moving "rightward", and $G(x+ct)$ moving "leftward" (though waves could exist in any dimension of course, taking $x\in\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: @Nico: however, another common use of the word is quantum-mechanical, and there a “wave” or “wave-function” is a solution to the Schrödinger equation, instead. Still, I broadly agree with your suggestion; in general, a wave is a solution to some “oscillatory” partial differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I have found for the definition of a “wave” in physics is “a disturbance that propagates through a medium, or through a field of some sort”. (The “field” refers to a vector field, or a more general tensor field). This is, of course, not a precise definition but it is the best I can find, at this level of generality.

I have forgotten where I read this definition, some physics textbook.